# Out of memory error java heap space using InputStream. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, gzip, inputstream, heap-memory

I'm trying to read each file in a directory that contains 4000 json.gz files.
I'm running out of heap space during execution. I'm unsure how to solve this.

```
        File folder = new File(directoryPath);
        String [] files = folder.list();

        assert files != null;

        for (String file: files) {
            String filePath = directoryPath + "/" + file;

            if (filePath.substring(filePath.length() - 2).equalsIgnoreCase("gz")) {
                
                try (GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath))) {
                    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzipInputStream);

                    Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);

                    TextFileModel textFileModel = processObject(obj, controller);
                    textFileModelList.add(textFileModel);
                    
                } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
          }
```

UPDATE:

I've tried a few of the suggestions but I'm still getting the same error

```
try (InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath)))){

                    Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);

                    reader.close();

                    TextFileModel textFileModel = processObject(obj, controller);
                    obj = null;
                    textFileModelList.add(textFileModel);

                } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:668)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)
    at com.sbl.Main.main(Main.java:45)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error)

Comment: Do you need to keep all those objects in memory (simultaneously)? If yes -> increase heap. If not -> dereference all objects that are no longer needed

Comment: How do you dereference input streams(reader) ?

Comment: You should close the stream when you're finished with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to process the files as you read them, perhaps writing then to an alternate file or directory.  You can also set the heap space using one of the `java -Xm*` options assuming your platform has sufficient memory to support it.

```
java -Xmn<size>        sets the initial and maximum size (in bytes) of the heap
                      for the young generation (nursery)
java -Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
java -Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
```

If your using and IDE, you should be able to configure it as well.  In Eclipse you can edit the `Run Configuration` for your applications and set the options there.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to increase the heap memory, you can specify the `-Xmx` option to set the Maximum heap memory available for JVM and `Xms` for Minimum heap memory.

You can set these as specified in the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763095/8175739

Also, try defining the `InputStreamReader` in the try block so it can be closed too -

```java
try (GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath)); 
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzipInputStream)) {
    Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);      
    ...
}
```